# Configuring vmware in windows 7 home basic

Tags: windows-7

I have an HP laptop with windows 7 home basic.  I want to install Ubuntu 12.041 on my laptop. How can I configure Ubuntu 12.041 on my laptop without uninstalling windows 7 home basic?

Comment: One way: You gotta check if the CPU of your laptop supports Virtualization and then install either VMplayer or VirtualBox after that grab the iso of Ubuntu from their site and provide it to your Guest image. The other way: Partition your drive so you can get another drive you can install Ubuntu on and then boot from LiveDisk and install it to that partition. Personally I would go with the first option.

Answer (score 0):

Download Virtualbox and Ubuntu:

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Install Vbox and run it. Click on new (or Machine > New), give it a name, select Linux and Ubuntu. Continue through the wizard. Most settings should be fine. I might make the virtual hard disk somewhere around 30GB if you aren't planning on doing things with extremely large files on it. Start the machine and it should prompt you for an ISO file to use as the boot CD. Use the Ubuntu one you downloaded earlier. If you need any more help feel free to comment or I'm sure you can find lots of info by searching Google.